# Load divX from page2 into page 1 using jsonp to bypass same origin policy

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jquery-callback

I'm trying to load a div from another page using this,

```
$('#result').load('page2.php #divX')
```

but the JavaScript contained in that page won't work even though page1 and page two are using the same JavaScript file linked at the head of both pages. So i assume this is the same origin policy. How do i do this using jquery and json to bypass this restriction?

Something like this Ajax but i don't know where to go from here.

```
(function($) {
    var url = 'page2';
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I understand i have to write some callback at page2 if I'm not wrong, how do I do that?

Additions.

Here's Page1.

```
$('#Loadfrompage2').click(function() {
$('#result').load('../page2.php #divX')
});
```

Page.2 Content.

```
<div id="divX">
            <input name="B" type="submit" value=" ">
            <input name="P" type="submit" id="Q" value=" ">
             <input name="A" type="submit" value=" ">
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: Errors for .Load? if you mean that im not getting any errors.

Comment: Not even some error/warning about same-origin policy?

Comment: you can't use `jsonp` to grab `html` from another page.The url has to output data as `jsonp`. Can use Yahoo YUI to get  html from another domain ( delivered as jsonp), or scrape it yourself from your server

Comment: explain in more detail source of these pages, if different domains do you control both? Could also be that issue is related to expecting code bound to html not working for same elements loaded dynamically...which is easy to fix

Comment: @charlietfl It's not different domains, its the same domain on different pages. after loading divX from page2 into page1 using jquery's .load, the buttons and links inside divX loaded from page2 won't respond to any clicks.

Comment: OK... need to delegate event handlers.... when you replace elements...even with same html...lose any event handlers bound to them. Also, if elements don't exist when code is run, new ones won't be included without delegating the handlers. Provide some sample markup and clcik handler code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to managing code for newly inserted html such as when using `load()`. Either you have to run any event binding code ( or plugins) on the new elements after they are inserted , or you have to use event delgation that binds to elements further up the DOM tree that are permament assets in the page

Delegation approach ( accounts for future or replaced elements):

Instead of `$('.myButtonclass').click....` use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myButtonclass', function(){

    /* same code you already have in current click handler*/

})
```

After insertion approach:

```
$('#content').load('path/to/server', function(){
   /* new html exist now*/
   $(this).find('.buttonClass').click....
})
```

FYI- `jsonp` is used for retrieving JSON data cross domain... is very different than html. Subject of this thread got confusing due to reference to `jsonp`